# How to open Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info

Tags: fedora, windows, libreoffice, file-format

Output of *file* command for a given odt file gives me

```
Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info.
```

By searching on Google I found it a doc document and I installed *unoconv* to read it on linux(fedora). But when I  run the command:

```
 unoconv -d document --format=odt file.doc
```

I get the following error:

```
unoconv: RuntimeException during import phase:Office probably died. Unsupported URL  Thumb.doc: "type detection failed"**.
```

I am having all packages of libreoffice writer. So how do I open these kind of files on fedora?

Comment: Make sure you installed libreoffice from official Fedora repo correctly and your file isn't corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a URI-format for the input:

```
unoconv -o /absolute/path/to/file.pdf file://$PWD/file.doc
```

the error message is poor processing of the tool and not related to the data.
I also found the output works only if an absolute path is given.